# Unknown authentication scheme on LinkedIn API

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api, pecl, linkedin-jsapi

I'm using OAuth 1.0a for LinkedIn API. Currently, I've already implemented some calls for getting the profile and connections and they all seem to work fine. But for sending a message, the oauth library throws an exception with the following:

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Unknown authentication scheme",
  "requestId": "I2Y0MFJ8ME",
  "status": 401,
  "timestamp": 1378376573339
}
```

I'm using PHP PECL OAuth. I'm initializing the $oauth object like this:

```
$oauth = new OAuth(API_KEY, API_SECRET, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_FORM);
$oauth->setToken(ACCESS_TOKEN, SECRET);
```

and making the rest call like this:

```
$url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/mailbox?format=json';
$content_type = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');
$oauth->fetch($url, $message, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, $content_type);
```

and $message looks something like this:

```
$message = Array
(
    [recipients] => Array
        (
            [0] => z2222117O
        )

    [subject] => this is my title
    [body] => this is my body
    [format] => json
    [id] => EAS123123
)
```

It doesn't look like there's anything wrong with the request. I've followed the instructions from the [LinkedIn messaging docs](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/messaging-between-connections-api). Anyone else had the same problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I have answer the question on the below link, seems the same error. Though it seems different technology, but solution would be same to send the access_token in request back to get the protected resources.

The link for your reference.
[Apache Oltu Linkedin Integration example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755678/apache-oltu-linkedin-integration-example/29755905#29755905)

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn requires you to either set the access token in the header or as a query param with the non-standard name of `oauth2_access_token`. When I sent it as a query param with the name `access_token`, I got the error you did.

Answer (score 0):

Some questions on the [LinkedIn forums](http://developer.linkedin.com/forum) seem to indicate that the error you're getting means that you don't have a valid authentication token.

Are you sure you're sending a correct and active auth token with your message?

Comment: Yes, I've double checked the token and it's still valid. And it also works for other API requests (get profile, share on wall, etc).